# Python math calculation proportional

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, calculator

I'm trying to do a proportional calculation in Python. I am just at the point where I have to recognize the values as proportional or not proportional before I can calculate

As a typical default a text.

20 workers need 15 days with 8 hours each to paint the apartment.
How many hours per day would 24 workers have to work if the job is to be completed in 12 days.

Logically, I would proceed as follows

```
Worker      Days     
20          15       8 hours 
24          12
```

In this case, both values are not proportional, as less becomes more. Or more to less.

How can I combine this detection whether proportional or disproportional in one formula?

In example, I have some num values

```
Num_worker_1 = 20
Num_worker_2 = 24
Num_days_1 = 15
Num_days_2 = 12
Num_hours_1 = 8
Num_hours_2 = ??
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the fact that less becomes more doesn't mean the values aren't proportional, inverse proportion exists.

Comment: what does "proportional" mean to you?  the problem isn't python or computing; it's a lack of precision in your requirement.

Comment: when you say "in 12 hours" you mean "in 12 days"?

Comment: Yes, I would likt to detect, is proportion exists. I changed to 12 days, youre right

Comment: I think that this question might do better over at [Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), as it seems there is a convenient mathematical equation for what you want to do.  If you need help programming that equation later, the StackOverflow is the place to come.

Comment: @Sama you need to formulate the problem. I suggest you to look at Python package CVXPY which allows you to solve linearised problems (LP problems).

Comment: I assume that they need the same total number of hours - `(20*15*8) = (24*12*X)` - so `X = (20*15*8)/(24*12)` and this give me `X = 8.3333`

Answer (score 1):

I provide first a trivial approach to the problem where I assume that each worker have the same efficiency and the same capacity to work. Lastly, I provide you library that you could use to formulate the problem as Linear Programming task (LP) and then solve with it.

**Proportionally each worker having the same total amount of work in hours and efficiency**

You need 2400 man hours to complete the work

```
>>> 20*8*15
2400
```

so for 24 workers, you have

```
2400 = 24 * D
```

where D is work per day so `D = 2400.0/24`

```
>>> 2400.0/24 
100
```

so each man has to work 100 hours during the 12 days.

**How is it if workers have different capacity to work?**

It means more constraints which you solve as a linear optimisation problem (LP). I suggest you to look at Python package such as CVXPY for convex optimisation [here](https://www.cvxpy.org/).